# Spring Roo @Transient not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-roo, spring-data-jpa

these are the frameworks that I'm using: spring MVC 3.2.3, Roo 1.2.4 and ava 1.7.

I have added a Transient field to Item domain as follow:

```
@Transient
private Long hierarchyNbr;
```

And on saving the entity

> entityRepository.saveAndFlush(obj)

I'm getting the following exception:

> Hibernate: 
>       insert 
>       into
>           dbo.Item
>           (CreateTs, CreateUser, Descr, ForAnyCompanyInd, hierarchyNbr, IdIndustry, IdUom, IsClassifiedInd, IsParentInd, LastUpdateTs, LastUpdateUser) 
>       values
>           (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   2014-07-25 10:48:09,580 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid column name 'hierarchyNbr'.

According to my understanding **hierarchyNbr** field should **NOT** be persisted, isn't it ?

So, can someone help me with this case?

Comment: What is the import you are using for `@Transient`?

Comment: I need a field in my domain object that is not going to be persisted, and this is not in the table.

Comment: Sorry here is: org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `javax.persistence.Transient`.

You are using [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html) transient annotation which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should use javax.persistence.Transient annotation.